# wagtail search in custom searchfields is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, django-models, wagtail

I am implementing a simple blog in wagtail. In the case of the blog pages the search should also look into the two custom fields 'intro' and 'body'. My BlogPage-model is as follows:

```
class PageWithSidebar(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(PageWithSidebar, self).get_context(request)
        context['tags'] = BlogPageTag.objects.all().select_related().values('tag_id', 'tag_id__name').annotate(item_count=Count('tag_id')).order_by('-item_count')[:10]
        context['categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.values('name').annotate(Count('name')).values('name').order_by('name')
        context['recent_blogpages'] = Page.objects.filter(content_type__model='blogpage').filter(live='1').order_by('-first_published_at')

        return context

class BlogPage(PageWithSidebar):


date = models.DateField("Post date")
        intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        body = RichTextField(blank=True)
        tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
        categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)
        social_description = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)

        def main_image(self):
            gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
            if gallery_item:
                return gallery_item.image
            else:
                return None

        def main_image_caption(self):
            gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
            if gallery_item:
                return gallery_item.caption
            else:
                return None

        search_fields = PageWithSidebar.search_fields + [
            index.SearchField('intro'),
            index.SearchField('body'),
        ]

        content_panels = PageWithSidebar.content_panels + [
            MultiFieldPanel([
                FieldPanel('date'),
                FieldPanel('tags'),
                FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
                FieldPanel('social_description'),
            ], heading="Blog information"),
            FieldPanel('intro'),
            FieldPanel('body'),
            InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
        ]
```

The search works just fine for the 'title' field but not for the two custom fields. I just get no results if I search for words which are just contained in the 'intro' or 'body' field.

Any ideas what i am missing?

Comment: Which search backend are you using? The default backend is limited and does not support custom fields

Comment: I was using the default one. After actually setting up elasticsearch everything works as expected. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that the default search backend doesn't support custom fields. After switching to elasticsearch the custom fields were included.

Comment: FYI: I just found out that Wagtail v1.10 also supports full-text search for Postgres, which would drop the need for Elasticsearch

Comment: Nice info! Thanks